# ssh + along delay after typing the password between win to linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, unix

I installed two Linux machines with Linux version - 5.5.1.0-01

Something is very strange
if I perform ssh between Linux to Linux after I type the password I get the prompt of the second Linux machine without any delay

But if I perform ssh from window VIA (putty/reflection)  to the Linux machines  , after I type the password I have a long delay like 6 seconds

so please advice why I get delay when I connect to linux machine from windows

and I not get any delay when I perform ssh between Linux machines

Remark 
I have two Linux machine – 5.5 version + PC with windows XP all machines connected to the switch with 1G speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause of that sort of delay in ssh is DNS resolution of the client.  On the ssh server, can you not do a reverse lookup of the Windows client machine's IP address?  Does the same lookup work for the Linux clients?

If that's the case, add the following line to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the server to disable the DNS lookup of the IP address:

`UseDNS no`

You can also take a look at the OpenSSH FAQ entry for this sort of problem: http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.3

Answer (score 1):

Usually this problem arises due to the 'Reverse DNS Lookup' the SSH daemon performs on the connection client ip.
To disable this reverse dns lookup add to your sshd-configfile the following line:

UseDNS no

disabeling the reverse DNS shouldn't impact your standard security parameters at all.